# live migration on KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, live-migration

I knew that the KVM can be run in ATOM server processor ( because ATOM server processor support intel-VTx ).

But I'm wondering it is possible "live migration" in ATOM server.

Who know about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible as long as the destination host is at the same level of CPU capabilities or higher